# 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'LoginController' in type cast in GETX Flutter

Tags: flutter-state, flutter-getx

I am using  nullsafety  and following code produce error . The error is type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'LoginController' in type cast.

```
home: Obx(() {
          if (controller.authState == "Authenticated") {
            return HomeView();
          } else {
            return LoginView();
          }
        }));
```

Please suggest a correct approach.

Comment: can u post code of LoginController as well

Answer (score 0):

Initialize authstate in your getx controller

```
enum Status { authenticated,notauthorized}

class Controller extends GetxController
{
Rx<Status> status = Status.notauthorized.obs;
}
```

Or you may not intialized logincontroller

```
final LoginController logincontroller =
  Get.put(LoginController());
```

in your page